# doctrine/reflection conflicts with doctrine/common

Tags: upgrading, 9

My current Drupal version is 8.9.3, running on PHP 7.3.20, and updated from Drupal 8.9.2 (fresh install) using `compose update`.

I tried to upgrade to Drupal 9 used this https://www.drupal.org/docs/upgrading-drupal/upgrading-from-drupal-8-to-drupal-9-or-higher as guide. So in step 2, I ran `composer require "drupal/core:9.0.0 as 8.9.3" --no-update && composer update` instead of `composer require drupal/core-recommended:^9.0.0 drupal/core-composer-scaffold:^9.0.0 drupal/core-project-message:^9.0.0 --update-with-dependencies --no-update`, but then Composer throws a conflict report regarding doctrine/reflection which conflicts with doctrine/common.

```
  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: remove drupal/core-recommended 8.9.3
    - drupal/core-recommended 8.8.x-dev requires drupal/core 8.8.x-dev -> satisfiable by drupal/core[8.8.x-dev].
    - drupal/core-recommended 8.9.x-dev requires drupal/core 8.9.x-dev -> satisfiable by drupal/core[8.9.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: drupal/core[9.0.0, 8.8.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: drupal/core[9.0.0, 8.9.x-dev].
    - drupal/core-recommended 8.9.2 requires drupal/core 8.9.2 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[8.9.2] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - drupal/core-recommended 8.9.1 requires drupal/core 8.9.1 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[8.9.1] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - drupal/core-recommended 8.9.0-rc1 requires drupal/core 8.9.0-rc1 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[8.9.0-rc1] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - drupal/core-recommended 8.9.0-beta3 requires drupal/core 8.9.0-beta3 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[8.9.0-beta3] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - drupal/core-recommended 8.9.0-beta2 requires drupal/core 8.9.0-beta2 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[8.9.0-beta2] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - drupal/core-recommended 8.9.0-beta1 requires drupal/core 8.9.0-beta1 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[8.9.0-beta1] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - drupal/core-recommended 8.9.0 requires drupal/core 8.9.0 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[8.9.0] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - drupal/core-recommended 8.8.8 requires drupal/core 8.8.8 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[8.8.8] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - drupal/core-recommended 8.8.7 requires drupal/core 8.8.7 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[8.8.7] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - drupal/core-recommended 8.8.6 requires drupal/core 8.8.6 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[8.8.6] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - drupal/core-recommended 8.8.5 requires drupal/core 8.8.5 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[8.8.5] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - drupal/core-recommended 8.8.4 requires drupal/core 8.8.4 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[8.8.4] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - drupal/core-recommended 8.8.3 requires drupal/core 8.8.3 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[8.8.3] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - drupal/core-recommended 8.8.2 requires drupal/core 8.8.2 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[8.8.2] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - drupal/core-recommended 8.8.1 requires drupal/core 8.8.1 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[8.8.1] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - drupal/core-recommended 8.8.0-rc1 requires drupal/core 8.8.0-rc1 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[8.8.0-rc1] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - drupal/core-recommended 8.8.0-beta1 requires drupal/core 8.8.0-beta1 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[8.8.0-beta1] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - drupal/core-recommended 8.8.0 requires drupal/core 8.8.0 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[8.8.0] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - Installation request for drupal/core 9.0.0 as 8.9.3 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[9.0.0].
    - Installation request for drupal/core-recommended ^8.8 -> satisfiable by drupal/core-recommended[8.8.0, 8.8.0-beta1, 8.8.0-rc1, 8.8.1, 8.8.2, 8.8.3, 8.8.4, 8.8.5, 8.8.6, 8.8.7, 8.8.8, 8.8.x-dev, 8.9.0, 8.9.0-beta1, 8.9.0-beta2, 8.9.0-beta3, 8.9.0-rc1, 8.9.1, 8.9.2, 8.9.3, 8.9.x-dev].
    - drupal/core 9.0.0 requires doctrine/reflection ^1.1 -> satisfiable by doctrine/reflection[1.1.x-dev, 1.2.0, 1.2.1, 1.2.x-dev, 1.3.x-dev, v1.1.0].
    - doctrine/reflection 1.1.x-dev conflicts with doctrine/common[v2.7.3].
    - doctrine/reflection 1.2.0 conflicts with doctrine/common[v2.7.3].
    - doctrine/reflection 1.2.1 conflicts with doctrine/common[v2.7.3].
    - doctrine/reflection 1.2.x-dev conflicts with doctrine/common[v2.7.3].
    - doctrine/reflection 1.3.x-dev conflicts with doctrine/common[v2.7.3].
    - doctrine/reflection v1.1.0 conflicts with doctrine/common[v2.7.3].
    - drupal/core-recommended 8.9.3 requires doctrine/common v2.7.3 -> satisfiable by doctrine/common[v2.7.3].
    - Conclusion: remove doctrine/common v2.7.3
```

I don't know what to do as I assumed it is a core modules conflict issue.

How do I fix this upgrade issue?

`composer show` shows the following output.

```
asm89/stack-cors                     1.3.0           Cross-origin resource sharing library and stack middleware
composer/installers                  v1.9.0          A multi-framework Composer library installer
composer/semver                      1.5.1           Semver library that offers utilities, version constraint parsing and validation.
container-interop/container-interop  1.2.0           Promoting the interoperability of container objects (DIC, SL, etc.)
doctrine/annotations                 v1.4.0          Docblock Annotations Parser
doctrine/cache                       v1.6.2          Caching library offering an object-oriented API for many cache backends
doctrine/collections                 v1.4.0          Collections Abstraction library
doctrine/common                      v2.7.3          Common Library for Doctrine projects
doctrine/inflector                   v1.2.0          Common String Manipulations with regard to casing and singular/plural rules.
doctrine/lexer                       1.0.2           PHP Doctrine Lexer parser library that can be used in Top-Down, Recursive Descent Parsers.
drupal/admin_toolbar                 2.3.0           Provides a drop-down menu interface to the core Drupal Toolbar.
drupal/allowed_formats               1.3.0           Limit which text formats are available for each field instance.
drupal/amswap                        3.0.0           Allows the administration menu to be customised per user role.
drupal/asset_injector                2.7.0           Adds CSS or JS to the page output based on configurable rules.
drupal/auto_entitylabel              3.0.0-beta3     Allows hiding of entity label fields and automatic label creation.
drupal/basic_watermark               1.0.0-alpha3    Watermark image style effect for Drupal.
drupal/blazy                         2.1.0           Provides basic bLazy integration for lazy loading and multi-serving images.
drupal/bootstrap_barrio              5.0.1           Bootstrap 4 base theme.
drupal/bootstrap_library             1.13.0          Provides Bootstrap Integration.
drupal/captcha                       1.1.0           The CAPTCHA module provides this feature to virtually any user facing web form on a Drupa...
drupal/cdn                           3.5.0           Serves files (CSS, JS, images …) from a CDN.
drupal/colorbox                      1.6.0           A light-weight, customizable lightbox plugin for jQuery.
drupal/core                          8.9.3           Drupal is an open source content management platform powering millions of websites and ap...
drupal/core-composer-scaffold        8.9.3           A flexible Composer project scaffold builder.
drupal/core-project-message          8.9.3           Adds a message after Composer installation.
drupal/core-recommended              8.9.3           Locked core dependencies; require this project INSTEAD OF drupal/core.
drupal/ctools                        3.4.0           Provides a number of utility and helper APIs for Drupal developers and site builders.
drupal/ds                            3.8.0           Extend the display options for every entity type.
drupal/easy_breadcrumb               1.13.0          Adds configuration to the system breadcrumbs.
drupal/entity_browser                2.5.0           Entity browsing and selecting component.
drupal/entity_clone                  1.0.0-beta4     Add a clone action for all entities
drupal/entity_reference_revisions    1.8.0           Entity Reference Revisions
drupal/field_formatter_class         1.4.0           Provides custom HTML class settings for field formatters.
drupal/field_group                   3.1.0           Provides the field_group module.
drupal/field_permissions             1.0.0           The Field Permissions module allows site administrators to set field-level permissions to...
drupal/file_download_link            1.0.0           Adds field formatter to render file field as configurable download link.
drupal/file_mdm                      2.1.0           Provides a service to manage file metadata.
drupal/file_mdm_exif                 2.1.0           Provides a file metadata plugin for EXIF image information.
drupal/file_mdm_font                 2.1.0           Provides a file metadata plugin for TTF/OTF/WOFF font information.
drupal/flexslider                    2.0.0-rc2       FlexSlider 2 integration for Drupal
drupal/fontawesome                   2.17.0          The web's most popular icon set and toolkit.
drupal/fontyourface                  3.2.0           Web font management tools.
drupal/git_deploy                    2.3.0           Helps sites that are deployed directly from Git repositories.
drupal/google_analytics              3.1.0           Allows your site to be tracked by Google Analytics by adding a Javascript tracking code t...
drupal/image_effects                 3.0.0           Provides effects and operations for the Image API.
drupal/imagefield_tokens             2.21.0          Provides new widget type for Image field to allow to use tokens for filling Alt and Title...
drupal/libraries                     3.0.0-alpha1    Allows version-dependent and shared usage of external libraries in Drupal.
drupal/login_security                1.5.0           Enable security options in the login flow of the site.
drupal/mailsystem                    4.3.0           Mail System
drupal/maxlength                     1.0.0-rc1       Limit the number of characters in textfields and textareas and shows the amount of charac...
drupal/memcache                      2.1.0           High performance integration with memcache.
drupal/menu_item_role_access         2.0.0           Provide role based access to menu items.
drupal/metatag                       1.13.0          Manage meta tags for all entities.
drupal/paragraphs                    1.12.0          Enables the creation of Paragraphs entities.
drupal/paragraphs_collapsible        1.2.0           Improves the Paragraphs widget by applying CSS tweaks and collapsible feature
drupal/pathauto                      1.8.0           Provides a mechanism for modules to automatically generate aliases for the content they m...
drupal/pdf                           1.0.0           Display PDF file in Drupal without external readers and plugins.
drupal/phpmailer                     3.0.0-beta1     Integrates the PHPMailer library for SMTP e-mail delivery.
drupal/phpmailer_smtp                1.5.0           Uses the PHPMailer library to send emails via SMTP.
drupal/recaptcha                     3.0.0           Protect your website from spam and abuse while letting real people pass through with ease.
drupal/redirect                      1.6.0           Allows users to redirect from old URLs to new URLs.
drupal/remove_http_headers           1.0.0-beta3     Removes configured HTTP Response headers.
drupal/rename_admin_paths            2.0.0           The purpose of this module is to secure drupal backend by renaming the admin paths.
drupal/shs                           1.0.0-alpha4    Creates a simple hierarchical select widget for taxonomy fields.
drupal/slick                         2.2.0           Slick carousel, the last carousel you'll ever need.
drupal/slick_views                   2.3.0           Provides Slick carousel integration with Views. Slick carousel, the last carousel you'll ...
drupal/social_media                  1.8.0           Share current page to social media
drupal/stickynav                     1.1.0           Module to make navigation on the website sticky when you scroll down the page.
drupal/taxonomy_manager              1.0.0-beta2     Tool for administrating taxonomy terms.
drupal/taxonomy_menu                 3.4.0           Creates menu items based on associations to taxonomy vocabularies
drupal/token                         1.7.0           Provides a user interface for the Token API, some missing core tokens.
drupal/token_filter                  1.2.0           This is a very simple module to make global token values available as an input filter.
drupal/typed_data                    1.0.0-alpha5    Extends the core Typed Data API with new APIs and features.
drupal/upgrade_status                2.9.0           Review current status of known Drupal 9 incompatibilities on the site.
drupal/video_embed_field             2.4.0           A pluggable field type for storing videos from external video hosts such as Vimeo and You...
drupal/views_fieldsets               3.x-dev eea8080 Adds fieldsets to Views.
drupal/views_show_more               1.0.0           Provide a show more pager plugin for Views.
drupal/xmlsitemap                    1.0.0           Creates XML sitemaps for the site
easyrdf/easyrdf                      0.9.1           EasyRdf is a PHP library designed to make it easy to consume and produce RDF.
egulias/email-validator              2.1.17          A library for validating emails against several RFCs
google/recaptcha                     1.2.4           Client library for reCAPTCHA, a free service that protects websites from spam and abuse.
guzzlehttp/guzzle                    6.5.4           Guzzle is a PHP HTTP client library
guzzlehttp/promises                  v1.3.1          Guzzle promises library
guzzlehttp/psr7                      1.6.1           PSR-7 message implementation that also provides common utility methods
laminas/laminas-diactoros            1.8.7p2         PSR HTTP Message implementations
laminas/laminas-escaper              2.6.1           Securely and safely escape HTML, HTML attributes, JavaScript, CSS, and URLs
laminas/laminas-feed                 2.12.2          provides functionality for consuming RSS and Atom feeds
laminas/laminas-servicemanager       3.4.1           Factory-Driven Dependency Injection Container
laminas/laminas-stdlib               3.2.1           SPL extensions, array utilities, error handlers, and more
laminas/laminas-text                 2.7.1           Create FIGlets and text-based tables
laminas/laminas-zendframework-bridge 1.0.4           Alias legacy ZF class names to Laminas Project equivalents.
lsolesen/pel                         0.9.8           PHP Exif Library. A library for reading and writing Exif headers in JPEG and TIFF images ...
masterminds/html5                    2.3.0           An HTML5 parser and serializer.
mathieuviossat/arraytotexttable      v1.0.8          Display arrays in terminal
mglaman/phpstan-drupal               0.12.5          Drupal extension and rules for PHPStan
nette/finder                         v2.5.2           Nette Finder: find files and directories with an intuitive API.
nette/utils                          v3.1.2           Nette Utils: lightweight utilities for string & array manipulation, image handling, ...
nikic/php-parser                     v4.7.0          A PHP parser written in PHP
paragonie/random_compat              v9.99.99        PHP 5.x polyfill for random_bytes() and random_int() from PHP 7
pear/archive_tar                     1.4.9           Tar file management class with compression support (gzip, bzip2, lzma2)
pear/console_getopt                  v1.4.3          More info available on: http://pear.php.net/package/Console_Getopt
pear/pear-core-minimal               v1.10.10        Minimal set of PEAR core files to be used as composer dependency
pear/pear_exception                  v1.0.1          The PEAR Exception base class.
phenx/php-font-lib                   0.5.2           A library to read, parse, export and make subsets of different types of font files.
phpmailer/phpmailer                  v6.1.7          PHPMailer is a full-featured email creation and transfer class for PHP
phpstan/phpstan                      0.12.36         PHPStan - PHP Static Analysis Tool
phpstan/phpstan-deprecation-rules    0.12.5          PHPStan rules for detecting usage of deprecated classes, methods, properties, constants a...
psr/container                        1.0.0           Common Container Interface (PHP FIG PSR-11)
psr/http-message                     1.0.1           Common interface for HTTP messages
psr/log                              1.1.3           Common interface for logging libraries
ralouphie/getallheaders              3.0.3           A polyfill for getallheaders.
stack/builder                        v1.0.5          Builder for stack middlewares based on HttpKernelInterface.
symfony-cmf/routing                  1.4.1           Extends the Symfony2 routing component for dynamic routes and chaining several routers
symfony/class-loader                 v3.4.41         Symfony ClassLoader Component
symfony/console                      v3.4.41         Symfony Console Component
symfony/debug                        v3.4.41         Symfony Debug Component
symfony/dependency-injection         v3.4.41         Symfony DependencyInjection Component
symfony/event-dispatcher             v3.4.41         Symfony EventDispatcher Component
symfony/http-foundation              v3.4.41         Symfony HttpFoundation Component
symfony/http-kernel                  v3.4.41         Symfony HttpKernel Component
symfony/polyfill-ctype               v1.17.0         Symfony polyfill for ctype functions
symfony/polyfill-iconv               v1.17.0         Symfony polyfill for the Iconv extension
symfony/polyfill-intl-idn            v1.17.0         Symfony polyfill for intl's idn_to_ascii and idn_to_utf8 functions
symfony/polyfill-mbstring            v1.17.0         Symfony polyfill for the Mbstring extension
symfony/polyfill-php56               v1.17.0         Symfony polyfill backporting some PHP 5.6+ features to lower PHP versions
symfony/polyfill-php70               v1.17.0         Symfony polyfill backporting some PHP 7.0+ features to lower PHP versions
symfony/polyfill-php72               v1.17.0         Symfony polyfill backporting some PHP 7.2+ features to lower PHP versions
symfony/polyfill-util                v1.17.0         Symfony utilities for portability of PHP codes
symfony/process                      v3.4.41         Symfony Process Component
symfony/psr-http-message-bridge      v1.1.2          PSR HTTP message bridge
symfony/routing                      v3.4.41         Symfony Routing Component
symfony/serializer                   v3.4.41         Symfony Serializer Component
symfony/translation                  v3.4.41         Symfony Translation Component
symfony/validator                    v3.4.41         Symfony Validator Component
symfony/yaml                         v3.4.41         Symfony Yaml Component
twbs/bootstrap                       v4.5.2          The most popular front-end framework for developing responsive, mobile first projects on ...
twig/twig                            v1.42.5         Twig, the flexible, fast, and secure template language for PHP
typo3/phar-stream-wrapper            v3.1.4          Interceptors for PHP's native phar:// stream handling
webflo/drupal-finder                 1.2.0           Helper class to locate a Drupal installation from a given path.
```

Comment: `as 8.9.3` is not necessary and it's probably causing issues. You don't use `require` for upgrading; you use `update`.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, `composer require` doesn't seem to resolve version conflicts in the way `composer update` does. Your problem here is that Drupal 9 (`drupal/core-recommended:9.0.0`) requires `doctrine/reflection:1.2.1`, but `doctrine/reflection`, but [that packages indicates that it conflicts](https://packagist.org/packages/doctrine/reflection#v1.2.1) with `doctrine/common < 2.9`.

However, `doctrine/common:2.7.3` was required by Drupal 8, and this situation makes that you now must update `doctrine/common` and `doctrine/persistence` *at the same time*. `composer  require` doesn't seem to handle this well.

Probably the best way to fix this would be to edit your `composer.json` file manually and replace the version of `drupal/core-recommended` by `^9.0.0` and then run `bin/composer update`.